# Problems installing Moose on Mac (compile Sub::Name prereq)

Tags: perl, cpan, moose

I'm trying to install Moose (a CPAN module) on my Macbook Pro. It finds a dependency on Sub-Name, and when it tries to install this, gets the following error messages.  Any idea as to how I can cure this?

```
  XMATH/Sub-Name-0.04.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
  Running make test
  PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /opt/local/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/smoke....Can't load '/private/var/root/.cpan/build/Sub-Name-0.04-ziHbmm/blib/arch/auto/Sub/Name/Name.bundle' for module Sub::Name: dlopen(/private/var/root/.cpan/build/Sub-Name-0.04-ziHbmm/blib/arch/auto/Sub/Name/Name.bundle, 2): no suitable image found.  

Did find:
    /private/var/root/.cpan/build/Sub-Name-0.04-ziHbmm/blib/arch/auto/Sub/Name/Name.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at t/smoke.t line 6
Compilation failed in require at t/smoke.t line 6.
```

+++ Addendum +++

I tried the suggestion to use the command
  sudo port install p5-moose

The installation reported success, but a file with "use Moose'" in it, gives:

```
"Can't load '/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/auto/Class/C3/XS/XS.bundle' for module Class::C3::XS: dlopen(/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/auto/Class/C3/XS/XS.bundle, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/auto/Class/C3/XS/XS.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level/XSLoader.pm line 73.
 at /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/Class/C3/XS.pm line 48
Compilation failed in require at (eval 5) line 3.
```

I'm wondering if when I moved from my old machine (pre-Intel) to this one, if binaries got moved that I now need to re-compile. But, if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try installing Sub::Name via CPAN manually?

cpan> install Sub::Name

Also, I prefer to use port [http://www.macports.org/] on Mac to install Perl modules (or for that matter any other Open Source product).

1. It keeps what came with Mac OS untouched. So if Apple pushes a newer version with their OS updates, it wouldn't break my setup.
2. I can rollback changes I make with port.

Moose is available on macports and can be installed as:

sudo port install p5-moose

Answer (score 2):

Ouch, you should not have copied a perl installation from one machine to another.  It would be much better to start fresh with new installation(s).

I would strongly recommend nuking your macports directory (/opt/local) from orbit and starting over.  You can get a list of currently-installed packages with `port list installed`, but you could start by just installing the major applications that you need immediately, and then install other things later only as you need them.